# Java runtime could not be located” when starting VSCode with the Salesforce Extensions - Java Installed

Tags: salesforcedx, vs-code

I have followed the steps suggested on ["Java runtime could not be located" when starting VSCode with the Salesforce Extensions](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/212840/java-runtime-could-not-be-located-when-starting-vscode-with-the-salesforce-ext).

But now I still getting the following error "

> Code Editor for Visual Studio Code (Extension)
>   Java 8 is required to run. Download and install it from https://java.com/en/download/."

The version of Java installed is:

```
java version "1.8.0_181"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_181-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.181-b13, mixed mode)
Version of Visual Studio Code: 1.27.1
Apex Code Editor for Visual Studio Code: 43.15.0
```

Contents of `salesforcedx-vscode-apex.java.home`:

```
{
    "salesforcedx-vscode-apex.java.home": "/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_181/bin"
}
```

Anyone have any ideas on what's going on? I have also tried setting the environment path, but this has failed to make a difference.

Comment: This has worked for me -- `salesforcedx-vscode-apex.java.home":"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Java\\jre1.8.0_161"`. Can you try using this format? To me the current format you have looks to be mac oriented.

Comment: Hi, I have tried the following path: `"C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_181\\bin".` It's still not detecting Java 8.

I noticed that you are using the **32bit** version of the **JRE**, so I have tried to change the path to point to the JRE directory as follows, `"C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_181\\jre\\bin"` again no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it!!! Used the following: { "salesforcedx-vscode-apex.java.home": "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre" }

Comment: With jdk1.8.0_192, this does not work. Using single backslashes causes VS Code to interpret the following characters as escaped, so don't know if a previous version didn't, but even:

{ "salesforcedx-vscode-apex.java.home": "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_191\\jre" } still results in multiple "command not found" issues