# Getting an error "There are no entries to pick from" while creating LWC components

Tags: salesforcedx, lightning-web-components, vs-code

I am creating my first LWC component. While doing so When i run create LWC component command and then enter component name then I am getting an another input saying  "There are no entries to pick from" Enter desired directory.

I have tried entering `force-app/main/default/lwc, force-app, LWC/force-app/main/default/lwc` but nothing in working.
[image]

My project.json is

```
{
  "packageDirectories": [
    {
      "path": "force-app",
      "default": true
    }
  ],
  "namespace": "",
  "sfdcLoginUrl": "https://login.salesforce.com",
  "sourceApiVersion": "45.0"
}
```

I am running a windows machine.

Comment: Version of vscode and extension pack ? Also what happens when you just run the command to create the bundle  via the cli?

Comment: "sfdx force:lightning:component:create -n mycomponent --type lwc" on running this command error i am getting is "Lightning bundles must have a parent folder named 'lwc'."

Comment: What's the DX plugin version ?

Comment: Run sfdx plugins and see your vesrion

Comment: VS code is v1.19.3 and and while going through Extension i found out that Salesforce extension requires VS code v1.26 and higher. I will update and check again

Comment: Sfdx version is sfdx-cli/6.54.4-c01dcc69db

Comment: It was my VS code version issue.

Answer (score 1):

[image]Salesforce extensions pack only work for VS v1.26 and above.

Also for windows user add java runtime environment path. ["Java runtime could not be located" when starting VSCode with the Salesforce Extensions](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/212840/java-runtime-could-not-be-located-when-starting-vscode-with-the-salesforce-ext)

Check for version of java like for me it was "jre1.8.0_181"

```
"salesforcedx-vscode-apex.java.home": "/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_181"
```